# ClassCastException when trying to add child to parent in owned one to many. (using jdo on google appengine)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo, google-cloud-datastore

I need some help figuring out what I'm doing wrong here.  I am trying
to master one to many relationships and running into a roadblock.
I tried to modify the Employee and ContactInfo example to do one to
many mappings:

Everything works if I create both the parent (employee) and child
(Contact) and then call makePersistent.
But if I try to add a child object to an already persistent parent, I
get a java.lang.ClassCast exception.  The full stack trace is at the
bottom of the post.

Here is the code that breaks (If I move the makePersistent() call to
after the add(), everything works fine:

```
public void testOneToMany(){
      pm = newPM();
      Employee e = new Employee("peter");
      pm.makePersistent(e);
      Contact c = new Contact("123 main");
      List<Contact> contacts = e.getContacts();
      contacts.add(c); // here I get java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String
}
```

Here is the parent class

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class Employee {
 @PrimaryKey
 @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
 private Long id;

 @Persistent
 private String name;

 @Persistent(mappedBy="employee")
 private List<Contact> contacts;

 public Employee(String e){
         contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
         name = e;
 }

 List<Contact> getContacts(){
         return contacts;
 }

 Long getId(){
         return id;
 }

 public String getName(){
         return name;
 }

}
```

Here is the child class

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class Contact {
 @PrimaryKey
 @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
 private Key key;

 @Persistent
 private String streetAddress;

 @Persistent
 private Employee employee;

 public Contact(String s){
         streetAddress = s;
 }
 public String getAddress(){
         return streetAddress;
 }
 public Employee getEmployee(){
         return employee;
 }

}
```

Here's the full stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to
java.lang.String
        at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreRelationFieldManager
$1.setObjectViaMapping(DatastoreRelationFieldManager.java:148)
        at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreRelationFieldManager
$1.apply(DatastoreRelationFieldManager.java:108)
        at
org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreRelationFieldManager.storeRelations
(DatastoreRelationFieldManager.java:80)
        at
org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreFieldManager.storeRelations
(DatastoreFieldManager.java:770)
        at
org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertObject
(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:231)
        at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.internalMakePersistent
(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:3067)
        at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.makePersistent
(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:3043)
        at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.persistObjectInternal
(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1258)
        at org.datanucleus.sco.SCOUtils.validateObjectForWriting
(SCOUtils.java:1365)
        at
org.datanucleus.store.mapped.scostore.ElementContainerStore.validateElementForWriting
(ElementContainerStore.java:401)
        at
org.datanucleus.store.mapped.scostore.FKListStore.validateElementForWriting
(FKListStore.java:764)
        at org.datanucleus.store.mapped.scostore.FKListStore.internalAdd
(FKListStore.java:503)
        at org.datanucleus.store.mapped.scostore.AbstractListStore.add
(AbstractListStore.java:123)
        at org.datanucleus.sco.backed.List.add(List.java:752)
        at com.btg.plyus.scratch.JDOTest.testOneToMany(JDOTest.java:33)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:168)
        at com.btg.plyus.test.BaseTest.runTest(BaseTest.java:79)
        at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
        at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
        at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
        at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
        at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
        at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:232)
        at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:227)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.OldTestClassRunner.run
(OldTestClassRunner.java:76)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run
(JUnit4TestReference.java:45)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run
(TestExecution.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests
(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests
(RemoteTestRunner.java:673)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run
(RemoteTestRunner.java:386)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main
(RemoteTestRunner.java:196)
```

Comment: Can you try changing the PK in Employee from Long to Key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i dont think *you* are doing anything wrong.  this seems to be a bug with the vendor code.  see [this link](http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/issues/detail?id=59). there isnt a whole lot of info, but they intimate that the PK on your type `Long`  Employee.id is problematic.

Comment: sweet.  I will have to start searching the datanucleus groups as well as the app engine groups when i have an issue.

Comment: google should do, as it will bring up those sources as well as SO.

Answer (score 0):

Your database's id column isn't compatible with Long.  I don't think this has anything to do with the parent/child mapping.  If you want to confirm, please share your create statements.

Comment: I am using google's app-engine as the back end so there are no create statements.  Also, both entities are saved to the datastore if I do the makePersistent after adding the child.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you are trying this code on your local machine. Maybe this is a bug with GAE's Eclipse plugin, because, when you try to run this on production, it will run fine. I think the local version of the App Engine returns only `String` and not `Long` for a `Key`, or is it the other way around? Whatever be the case, it should run on production.